# Keycloak CODE_TO_TOKEN_ERROR error=invalid_client_credentials

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security, keycloak

I use:

- Spring Boot
- Koting
- Keycloak Version 4.4.0.Final

Keycloak is startet in Docker.

If I try to send a request with Postman to a simple REST-endpoint like:

```
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('MONITORING_ADMIN')") //this line is irrelevant, it doesn't matter
                                                    //whether I use it or not, the issue remains
    @PostMapping("/test")
    fun test() {
        println("test")
    }
```

then I will be redirected to login page (Valid Redirect URIs: http://localhost:8085/*)

The problem can be read in the Log  in Docker Console:

> keycloak_1  | 12:54:28,866 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-112) type=CODE_TO_TOKEN_ERROR, realmId=smight, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=172.19.0.1, error=invalid_client_credentials, grant_type=authorization_code

I define the Authorization with a Postman (Basic Auth)
Problem: ***client Id=null userId=null***
It can be that Keycloak doesn't see an userId, clientId or an Authorization header.

This is my Security Config:

```
@KeycloakConfiguration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
class WebSecurityConfig @Autowired constructor(val basicAuthenticationProvider: BasicAuthenticationProvider) : KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {
...
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        super.configure(http)

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").authenticated().anyRequest().permitAll()
    }

    @Bean
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter(): KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
        val requestMatcher = OrRequestMatcher(
                AntPathRequestMatcher(KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.DEFAULT_LOGIN_URL),
                QueryParamPresenceRequestMatcher(OAuth2Constants.ACCESS_TOKEN),

                // We provide our own authorization header matcher
                IgnoreKeycloakProcessingFilterRequestMatcher()
        )
        return KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter(authenticationManagerBean(), requestMatcher)
    }

   ...
    /**
     * Ignore the default keycloak processing once we receive a basic authentication request.
     */
    internal class IgnoreKeycloakProcessingFilterRequestMatcher : RequestMatcher {

        override fun matches(request: HttpServletRequest): Boolean {
            val authorizationHeaderValue = request.getHeader("Authorization")
            return authorizationHeaderValue != null && !authorizationHeaderValue.startsWith("Basic ")
        }
    }
}
```